# Is it possible to know in a destructor that an r-value referrence is being deleted?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor, move-semantics, raii

I was testing my own RAII pointer implementation that does some weird stuff (by design). To test it, I made a class that tracks constructors and destructors and makes sure everything is deleted and created exactly once.

But I was constantly getting an error that I'm deleting something twice. Weird, right. I found out why and you can see it by running the sample below.

This is not the code that originally produced it, but it demonstrates the issue.

```
struct ReportDelete
{
    ReportDelete() = delete;
    ReportDelete(const std::string& name) : name(name) { std::cout << "create " << name << "\n"; }
    ReportDelete(ReportDelete&& moveHere) : name(std::move(moveHere.name)) {}
    ReportDelete& operator=(ReportDelete&& moveHere)
    {
        name = std::move(moveHere.name);
        return *this;
    }

    ReportDelete(const ReportDelete&) = delete;
    void operator=(const ReportDelete&) = delete;

    std::string name;

    ~ReportDelete()
    {
        std::cout << "delete " << name << "\n";
        name = name + "-deleted";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::vector<ReportDelete> moveTest;
    moveTest.push_back(ReportDelete("test"));
}
```

This prints:

```
create test
delete
delete test
```

So the destructor is still called on the moved value. That does not do anything bad in particular, but it makes it impossible for me to test the create/delete ratio correctly.

My actual test class does this in the destructor:

```
        virtual ~Value() 
        {
            std::string error = name + " deleted twice!";
            assertm(parent.values[fullname()] == false, error.c_str());
            parent.values[fullname()] = true;
        }
```

Where parent is the class that tracks whether the values are deleted at the end. But how can I know here that this is only being run for `Value&&` and should be disregarded?

I tried this:

```
Value~() &&
{
    std::cout << "rvalue destructor ignored...\n";
}
```

But it seems you cannot have a special destructor like that.

How can I know that a destructor is being only called on an rvalue refference and that I can therefore ignore it and not track it as a real delete?

Comment: You could have a member variable `bool is_rvalue;` and set it to `true` if the object is an rvalue, and `false` if the object isn't an rvalue.

Comment: *"it makes it impossible for me to test the create/delete ratio correctly."* -- why? This seems to be the real problem, and your attempt to detect an r-value reference an XY problem.

Comment: @JaMiT See the comments under the answer. I named each test instance with a string and tracked that in a map. That was a problem because I'd either be "removing" an instance twice, or "removing" an instance whose name is empty (and therefore is not in the map). The proper solution is probably to remember that object was moved and treat that special.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica *"See the comments under the answer."* -- I'd rather see the information in the question, so that you are no longer presenting an XY problem. (Of course, any edits must not invalidate the existing answer.)

Comment: @JaMiT The concept of an XY problem is not really so smart. I asked the question this way, and that's what should be answered and solved for future readers finding this on google. There's nothing more frustrating than finding a question on google and it having different answer because of "XY problem". The answer here answers the question. If I wanted to ask "how to track when objects were deleted" I'd ask that.

Comment: @TomášZato *"I asked the question this way, and that's what should be answered and solved for future readers finding this on google."* -- this is an... "interesting" viewpoint, considering that you accepted an answer that did **not** answer the question that was asked. (In fact the opening sentence of that answer disputes the basis of your question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a destructor getting called for an r-value reference, or not. A destructor is a destructor. An object is getting destroyed. The End. The particular details of the object are immaterial.

```
ReportDelete& operator=(ReportDelete&& moveHere)
    {
        name = std::move(moveHere.name);
        return *this;
    }
```

This will move `name` from the moved-from instance of this object. However, the moved-from instance of the object is ***still a valid, existing object***, and at some point it ***will be destroyed***.

However you moved-from its `name` member. Your C++ implementation's result of that is that the moved-from `std::string` name is left to be an empty string.

And when that moved-from object gets destroyed its destructor prints an empty name. This is the output that you're seeing.

TLDR: you were not getting an error. What you overlooked is that a moved-from object is still a valid, existing object, and it is still subject to being destroyed. Which it will be, in a well-formed C++ program. In fact, because, in this case, the moved-from object is an rvalue reference that increases, quite significantly, the likelyhood that the moved-from object is about to get nuked from high orbit.

Comment: Yeah, I sort of figured that out eventually after asking this. I was getting an error in fact, but that's because my move ctor did not `std::move` the name. After moving it properly, it was empty, so I set up the test to ignore destructor when the name is empty.

Comment: This is not 100% correct. This particular compiler's C++ implementation leaves a moved-from `std::string` object as an empty string, but this is not required by the C++ standard. The C++ standard does not specify the state of a moved-from object, the only required is that the moved-from object must be in a "valid but unspecified state". It would not be entirely unreasonable if a different C++ compiler leaves a moved-from `std::string` completely unchanged. For best results you must find some other way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Ah. I thought it's stdlib that moves the string to the other one and therefore leaves the first one empty. I guess I can just have a boolean for refs that were already moved *from*.

Comment: That's what your C++ compiler's library does, of course. But, as I pointed out, this specific behavior is not required by the C++ standard.